# Dialogue box keeps popping up

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, sharedpreferences

I am using Flutter to build an app and trying to show an input dialogue box when app is run for the first time. For this I use shared preferences library. However, when I open the app, the dialogue box is shown every time regardless if it is the first time or not. Also, as I type a single letter in the input box, another dialogue box opens up in front of the previous one. I have attached the code below:

```
 class HomeMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeMenu> createState() => _HomeMenuState();
 }

class _HomeMenuState extends State<HomeMenu> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  var newLaunch;

  Future<void> showDialogIfFirstLoaded(BuildContext thisContext) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _newLaunch = prefs.getBool('newLaunch') ?? true;
    newLaunch = _newLaunch;
    if (newLaunch) {
      showDialog(
        context: thisContext,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: TextField(
              controller: textController,
              onChanged: (value) =>
                  setState(() => name = textController.text),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(thisContext);
                  prefs.setBool(newLaunch, false);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: tabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: [
           null
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling showDialogIfFirstLoaded in build method, and on TextFiled onChange method you are calling setState. Every time you call setState build method re-build again and it calling showDialogIfFirstLoaded on every setState.

I don't know your requirement but it not good to call setState in onChange method of TextField. You can use [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) if you require to update some part of UI on every single char type in text filed

If you want's to open that dialog only one time then create a method to get whether it's first launch or not and if yes then call showDialogIfFirstLoaded method.

For more details see below code -

```
   @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
        _isFirstLaunch();
      }
    
    _isFirstLaunch()async{
       final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       final bool? isfirstLaunch = prefs.getBool('first_launch');
       if(!isfirstLaunch ?? true){
        await prefs.setBool('first_launch', true);
        showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context);
       }

and update your build method like this -


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: tabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: [
           null
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to get the user input in the text box, so that I can use that string to display something in the UI. While your implementation works, the string isn't displayed in a widget on the screen, probably because the screen widgets have already been built at that point. Do you have any idea on how I can fix that?

Comment: Hey did you try  `ValueListenableBuilder`? or You can use `await` before showDialogIfFirstLoaded and then call setState, so every time when dialog will close screen will refresh or update your new code it will check an d will tell you the solution

Comment: I used await and setState and it works now, thank you!